# converting sql to hql query

Tags: sql, nhibernate, hql

Have to convert below working query into hql query. product and car is the domain.

```
Product {
long id
hasmany car: Car
string code
}
Car {
int no
int value
}

select p.id from products p
inner join car c on c.id=p.id and p.code='car'
inner join car cr on cr.id=p.id and p.code='car'
where c.no=1 and c.value>=10 and  c.no=2 and c.value<=30
```

Comment: Please show your objects `products` and `car`

Comment: @jen updated product and car in question

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the definition of your model it should be enough to do the following query

```
var query = session.CreateQuery("select p.id from Product p join p.car c" +
   " where c.no=1 " +
   " and c.value>=10 " +
   " and c.no=2 " +
   " and c.value<=30 " +
   " and p.code='car' ");
var results = query.List<int>();
```

with `session` being instance of `ISession` interface.

Comment: this query will never give answer since p.code wil  never contain value 1 and  2

Comment: @AnIshA in that case can you review your linq query ? It doesn't refer to `cr` alias and has only `and` conditions so I'm a bit confused on your end goal